# Defining input types in graphql-ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, react-apollo, graphql-ruby

I'm trying to implement an input type for filters with graphql-ruby and rails.

Base input type looks like:

```
module Types
  class BaseInputObject < GraphQL::Schema::InputObject
  end
end
```

My own input type looks like:

```
module Types
    class PhotoFilterType < Types::BaseInputObject
        argument :attribution, String, "Filters by submitter", required: false
        argument :country, String, "Filters by country", required: false
        argument :year, Int, "Filters by year", required: false
    end
end
```

query_type's method header looks like:

```
    field :filtered_photos, [Types::PhotoType], null: true do
      argument :filters, Types::PhotoFilterType, 'filters for photo', required: true
    end
```

And the query as follows:

```
const FILTER_QUERY = gql`
  query getFilteredPhotos($filters: PhotoFilterType!) {
    filteredPhotos(filters: $filters) {
      id
      title
      width
      height
    }
  }
`
```

Interacting with the backend using react-apollo as follows:

```
this.props.client.query({
      query: FILTER_QUERY,
      variables: {
        filters: {
          attribution: author.length > 0 ? author : '',
          country: country.length > 0 ? country : '',
          year: year ? year : 9999
        }
      }
    })
```

I get the following error

> {message: "PhotoFilterType isn't a defined input type (on $filters)",…}

But when I interact with rails console, I see:

```
irb(main):004:0> Types::PhotoFilterType
=> Types::PhotoFilterType
```

So I don't think the type being undefined is an issue.

Any idea what is going wrong and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you run this introspection query and paste the relevant output? https://gist.github.com/lunks/2e8dc2b3351b9a1741ff474c02570299

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem was solved by changing:

```
const FILTER_QUERY = gql`
  query getFilteredPhotos($filters: PhotoFilter!) { // not PhotoFilterType
    filteredPhotos(filters: $filters) {
      id
      title
      width
      height
    }
  }
`
```